# C# looks for non-existent file in contents rather than displaying contents

Tags: c#, file, io

I'm trying file I/O in C# (haven't done so at all before since I'm a beginner). I put a simple text file containing "some text" (literally) in the solution's resources, wrote some code based on online tutorials and pressed F5 to build. I was expecting "some text" to show up in the console window, but an exception did!

```
Could not find file 'F:\VS\FileTesting\FileTesting\bin\Debug\some text'.
```

As I said above, "some text" is the content of the file and its name is "important.txt"

Here's the code I'm using:

```
try
{
     /* using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Properties.Resources.important))
     {
          string line;

          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(line);
          }
     } */
     string contents = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.important);
     Console.WriteLine(contents);
     Console.WriteLine("Contents displayed successfully.");
     Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured. Exception: " + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

(the commented section above is from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166980/a-text-file-is-not-getting-displayed-to-the-console-in-c-sharp), which explained how to read a file line by line)

Based on @JonSkeet's comment below, I think I found the cause: it looks like `File.ReadAllText` reads and treats the contents of `Properties.Resources.important` as a filename rather than text as intended. "some text" is the only thing it can find, thus it searches a file with that name in the build directory, which is nonexistent. What I did was rename the original file to "pointer.txt", wrote "important.txt" in it and used it as a pointer to the file I want to read.

I can get away with having it read an external file, but I want the file in my resources. Plus, I can't seem to make it an embedded one - the option is disabled. Does that also have to do anything?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well presumably `Properties.Resources.important` is "some text". I strongly suspect if you look in your resource file, you'll see "some text", but it should be "important.txt".

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you so much! I made up something real quick based on your comment: I renamed the resource file to "pointer.txt" with "important.txt" in it and used it as a pointer. It works now!

Comment: I don't follow what you mean, but at the moment I don't think the question is going to help anyone, and there isn't enough information to really answer it. I would suggest you delete it, or edit it significantly to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `File` methods to read the contents of a resource. The `File` methods are for reading files from the file system.

To access the contents of the resource, simply write `Properties.Resources.important`. You can do `Console.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.important)` to write the contents of the resource to the console.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out later though since I'm away from my home.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried it and it works now. You also made the difference between a file in resources and a file in the file system clear to me.